# How to create a csv file from a formatted text file

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a text file with hundreds of prospects that I'm trying to convert to csv for importing.

Format for whole document.

Prospect Name

Description
Website

Prospect Name

Description
Website

How would I write a vb program to loop through this to make a csv file.  Every 4 lines is a new prospect.

Comment: To answer correctly to your question you need to show the format of the input file.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 0):

Get your file contents as an IEnumerable(of String), and spin through it, adding a CSV row for every record (into a new list(of String)).  Finally write the file contents.  You'll probably want to add a header row.

```
        Dim lstLines As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\test\ConvertToCSV.txt")

        Dim lstNewLines As New List(Of String)

        Dim intRecordTracker As Integer = 0

        Dim strCSVRow As String = String.Empty

        For Each strLine As String In lstLines

            If intRecordTracker = 4 Then

                intRecordTracker = 0

                'Trim off extra comma.
                lstNewLines.Add(strCSVRow.Substring(0, (strCSVRow.Length - 1)))

                strCSVRow = String.Empty

            End If

            strCSVRow += strLine & ","

            intRecordTracker += 1

        Next

        'Add the last record.
        lstNewLines.Add(strCSVRow.Substring(0, (strCSVRow.Length - 1)))

        'Finally write the CSV file.
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Test\ConvertedCSV.csv", lstNewLines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim count As Integer = -1, lstOutput As New List(Of String)

 lstOutput.AddRange(From b In File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\intput.txt").ToList.GroupBy(Function(x) (Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(count), count - 1) \ 4)).ToList() Select String.Join(",", b))

 File.WriteAllLines("c:\temp\test\output.txt", lstOutput)
```